# Convert unstructured data into a Python Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to convert the un-structured data into a python dictionary. This is how the data looks like:

```
main sub_main sub_main_1
 AAA A-ABC ABC
 AAA A-DEF A-DEF-GHI GHI
main sub_main sub_main_2
 BBB B-ABC ABC
 BBB B-DEF DEF
 BBB B-X B-Y B-Z ""
main sub_main sub_main_3
 CCC C-ABC  ABC
 CCC C-X C-Y C-Z ""
 CCC C-PQR C-STU 2
  C-LMN C-OPQ C-RST ""
 CCC C-DEF C-DEF-GHI ""
 CCC C-DEF C-DEF-JKL C-MNO 1
  C-XYZ ""
main sub_main sub_main_4
 DDD D-ABC  DEF
 DDD D-PQR  STU
main sub_main sub_main_5
 EEE E-ABC DEF
 EEE E-PQR STU
main sub_main sub_main_6
 FFF F-ABC  F-DEF
 FFF F-PQR  F-STU
```

Now, here are some conditions to convert this data into a a nested python dictionary.

1. Spaces at the beginning of each line defines the dictionary node level.
2. Each line can have the multiple keys. Such as, `CCC C-X C-Y C-Z 1` this should have four nested keys with `C-Z` will have `1` as a value(in case of child node, for parent node, check next point). Like this:

   ```
   'CCC': {'C-X': {'C-Y: 'C-Z': 1}}
   ```
3. If the next line has more space at the beginning, then the current line is a parent node and the next line will be a child node. In this scenario, the last item of the current line should be merged into a one single key with space as a separator between them. Like this:

   ```
    main sub_main sub_main_2
     BBB B-ABC ABC
   ```

   becomes:

   ```
   'main': {'sub_main sub_main_2': {'BBB': {'B-ABC': 'ABC'}}}
   ```

Now, this is the expected output:

```
{'main': {'sub_main sub_main_1': {'AAA': {'A-ABC': 'ABC',
                                          'A-DEF': {'A-DEF-GHI': 'GHI'}}},
          'sub_main sub_main_2': {'BBB': {'B-ABC': 'ABC',
                                          'B-DEF': 'DEF',
                                          'B-X': {'B-Y': {'B-Z': ''}}}},
          'sub_main sub_main_3': {'CCC': {'C-ABC': 'ABC',
                                          'C-DEF': {'C-DEF-JKL': {'C-MNO 1': {'C-XYZ': ''}},
                                                    'C-DEF-GHI': ''},
                                          'C-PQR': {'C-STU 2': {'C-LMN': {'C-OPQ': {'C-RST': ''}}}},
                                          'C-X': {'C-Y': {'C-Z': ''}}}},
          'sub_main sub_main_4': {'DDD': {'D-ABC': 'DEF',
                                          'D-PQR': 'STU'}},
          'sub_main sub_main_5': {'EEE': {'E-ABC': 'DEF',
                                          'E-PQR': 'STU'}},
          'sub_main sub_main_6': {'FFF': {'F-ABC': 'F-DEF',
                                          'F-PQR': 'F-STU'}}}}
```

And this is the code I am using:

```
def set_data(dic, key_list, key_name, value):
    """
    Set the value of key up to n depth
    :param dic: Output dictionary
    :param key_list: List of previous keys
    :param key_name: key name
    :param value: Value
    :return:
    """
    for key in key_list:
        # Get the value as per key, if key is missing then set with blank dictionary
        dic = dic.setdefault(key, {})
    # Set the value of the key_name
    dic[key_name] = value


def get_data(dic, key_list):
    """
    Get the value of key up to n depth
    :param dic: Output dictionary
    :param key_list: List of previous keys
    :param key_name: key name
    :return:
    """
    for key in key_list:
        # Get the value as per key, if key is missing then set with blank dictionary
        dic = dic.setdefault(key, {})
    return dic


def get_space_counter(input_list):
    """
    Get current space counter
    :param input_list:
    :return:
    """
    found_space = True
    space_counter = 0
    for j in input_list:
        if found_space and j == '':
            space_counter += 1
        else:
            break
    return space_counter


def set_val(temp, output, keys):
    """
    Set key, value pair of data upto n-2 keys in temp list
    :param temp: List of data
    :param output: Output dictionary
    :param keys: List of keys
    :return:
    """
    set_counter = 0
    for set_counter, i in enumerate(temp[:-2], start=1):
        if not get_dict_data(output, keys):
            set_dict_data(output, keys, i, {})
        keys.append(i)
    return set_counter


def custom_parser(input):
    """
    Parse unstructured data into a python dictionary
    :param input: Input data
    :return: Python dictionary
    """
    # Initialize the variables
    output = {}
    counter = 0
    keys = []
    key_line_counter = 0
    # Iterate through the input list data
    for i, input_str in enumerate(input):
        # Convert string into list based on empty space
        split_list = input_str.strip('\n').split(' ')
        # Get the initial space counter
        current_space_counter = get_space_counter(split_list)
        # Remove un-necessary space from the list
        new_temp = list(filter(lambda x: x != '', split_list[counter:]))
        try:
            # Try to find the initial space counter of the next string input
            next_split_list = input[i + 1].strip('\n').split(' ')
            next_space_counter = get_space_counter(next_split_list)
        except IndexError:
            next_space_counter = current_space_counter
        # If the current input space counter is less than the next input space counter,
        # that means the current input is the parent node and next input is the child node
        if current_space_counter < next_space_counter:
            # If Number of keys in each line is not equal to the current space counter
            # and the number of keys in each line is greater than 0 then pop the key from keys
            if key_line_counter != current_space_counter and key_line_counter > 0:
                for _ in range(key_line_counter + 1):
                    keys.pop()
            # Get the number of keys in each line
            set_counter = set_val(new_temp, output, keys)
            key_line_counter = set_counter
            # Generate key name, if the next line is the child node then in the current line,
            # last two items merged into one as a key with space as a separator
            key_name = f'{split_list[-2]} {split_list[-1]}'
            # Slice the keys
            keys = keys[:current_space_counter + set_counter + 1]
            # Set the key, value pair in output dictionary
            set_dict_data(output, keys, key_name, {})
            # Append the key_name into the keys list
            keys.append(key_name)
        else:
            # Get the number of keys in each line
            set_counter = set_val(new_temp, output, keys)
            # Set the key, value pair in output dictionary
            set_dict_data(output, keys[:current_space_counter + set_counter + key_line_counter + 1], new_temp[-2],
                          new_temp[-1].replace('"', ''))
            # As per the set_counter, pop the key from the keys list
            for _ in range(set_counter):
                keys.pop()
    return output


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(custom_parser(input_data))
```

And this is the output I am getting:

```
{'main': {'main': {'sub_main sub_main_5': {'EEE': {'E-ABC': 'DEF',
                                                   'E-PQR': 'STU'}},
                   'sub_main sub_main_6': {'FFF': {'F-ABC': 'F-DEF',
                                                   'F-PQR': 'F-STU'}}},
          'sub_main sub_main_1': {'AAA': {'A-ABC': 'ABC',
                                          'A-DEF': {'A-DEF-GHI': 'GHI'}}},
          'sub_main sub_main_2': {'BBB': {'B-ABC': 'ABC',
                                          'B-DEF': 'DEF',
                                          'B-X': {'B-Y': {'B-Z': ''}}}},
          'sub_main sub_main_3': {'CCC': {'C-ABC': 'ABC',
                                          'C-DEF': {'C-DEF-JKL': {'C-MNO 1': {'C-XYZ': ''}}},
                                          'C-PQR': {'C-STU 2': {'C-LMN': {'C-OPQ': {'C-RST': ''}},
                                                                'CCC': {'C-DEF': {},
                                                                        'C-DEF-GHI': ''}}},
                                          'C-X': {'C-Y': {'C-Z': ''}}},
                                  'sub_main sub_main_4': {'DDD': {'D-ABC': 'DEF',
                                                                  'D-PQR': 'STU'}}}}}
```

So, rather than mentioning explicitly, if you compare the expected and actual output(both are provided above), you'll get an idea on the issues I am facing in the problem. So, kindly guide me on how to solve these issues. Thank you.

Comment: In one case: `CCC C-X C-Y C-Z 1`  -> `'CCC': {'C-X': {'C-Y: 'C-Z': 1}}` each space represents a nested dict. In another the space is part of the key `main sub_main sub_main_2` -> `'main': {'sub_main sub_main_2':...` how do we tell the difference? In other words, why isn't the second case: `'main': {'sub_main':  {'sub_main_2'...`

Comment: @Mark, if it's a parent, then last two item will be merged into one.  Here `main sub_main sub_main_2`is the parent node, hence `sub_main sub_main_2` got merged into one and `CCC C-X C-Y C-Z 1`is the child node, hence it is in nested dictionary format.

Comment: I think the first question in the comments by @Mark was already explained in the text. What I am wondering is if the problem is completely described. For example, does the number of spaces at the start always increase by exactly 1? And if no, does a bigger gap have significance? Also, it appears that `""` should be interpreted to signify an empty string, but can double quotes appear in text elsewhere and if so, would they be escaped in some way?

Comment: @Grismar, Yes, the space always increase by 1. But it may decrease by any number. Also the empty string will always be as a value (last item), it would not appear elsewhere.

Comment: And `"` would not appear in any other names, or otherwise should just be interpreted as the character `"`, correct?

Comment: Also, there's extra spaces before `F-DEF` and `F-STU`, apparently extra spaces in between values should be ignored? (sorry for all the questions, but in the end a solution can only work correctly if the problem is sufficiently clearly defined)

Comment: @Grismar, yes, the `"` won't appear in any other names, otherwise we should just interpret as the character. Also, there might be extra spaces between the keys on the line, but it is just "space" and should be interpreted anything more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that was a bit more complicated than anticipated - but this solution does what you say you need, although it's a bit different from what you started out with:

```
from typing import Any, List, TextIO, Optional, Tuple
from io import StringIO

sample = StringIO("""main sub_main sub_main_1
 AAA A-ABC ABC
 AAA A-DEF A-DEF-GHI GHI
main sub_main sub_main_2
 BBB B-ABC ABC
 BBB B-DEF DEF
 BBB B-X B-Y B-Z ""
main sub_main sub_main_3
 CCC C-ABC  ABC
 CCC C-X C-Y C-Z ""
 CCC C-PQR C-STU 2
  C-LMN C-OPQ C-RST ""
 CCC C-DEF C-DEF-GHI ""
 CCC C-DEF C-DEF-JKL C-MNO 1
  C-XYZ ""
main sub_main sub_main_4
 DDD D-ABC  DEF
 DDD D-PQR  STU
main sub_main sub_main_5
 EEE E-ABC DEF
 EEE E-PQR STU
main sub_main sub_main_6
 FFF F-ABC  F-DEF
 FFF F-PQR  F-STU""")


def _dig(d: dict, keys: List[str], value: Any):
    """
    returns a copy of d, recursively updated with value using nested list of string keys
    """
    return d | {
        keys[0]: (
            _dig({}, keys[1:], value) if keys[0] not in d else _dig(d[keys[0]], keys[1:], value)
        ) if len(keys) > 1 else (value if value != '""' else '')}


def _data_to_dict(fp: TextIO, next_line: Optional[Tuple[int, str]], process_line: Optional[Tuple[int, str]], level: int):
    result = {}
    while True:
        # if there's no line to process, process next_line and load a new next_line
        if process_line is None:
            process_line = next_line
            try:
                line = next(fp)
                next_line = len(line) - len(line.lstrip()), [key for key in line.strip().split() if key]
            except StopIteration:
                # if no next_line could be read, done if process_line is None as well
                if process_line is None:
                    return next_line, result
                # otherwise, continue with next_line = None
                next_line = None
        else:
            # if the line to process is at the same or deeper level as the next line
            if next_line is None or process_line[0] >= next_line[0]:
                result = _dig(result, process_line[1][:-1], process_line[1][-1])
                if next_line is None or process_line[0] > next_line[0]:
                    return next_line, result
            else:  # prev_line[0] < line[0]
                next_line, sub = _data_to_dict(fp, next_line, None, level + 1)
                result = _dig(result, process_line[1][:-2] + [f'{process_line[1][-2]} {process_line[1][-1]}'], sub)
                if next_line is not None and next_line[0] < level:
                    return next_line, result
            process_line = None


def data_to_dict(fp: TextIO):
    __, result = _data_to_dict(fp, None, None, 0)
    return result


# operating on StringIO here, would work with open text file as well
print(data_to_dict(sample))
```

It doesn't pretty-print the dictionary, but you'll find it matches the structure you require.

In previous versions of Python, replace `_dig`, the `|` operator was added in 3.9.0:

```
def _dig(d: dict, keys: List[str], value: Any):
    """
    returns a copy of d, recursively updated with value using nested list of string keys
    """
    return {**d, **{
        keys[0]: (
            _dig({}, keys[1:], value) if keys[0] not in d else _dig(d[keys[0]], keys[1:], value)
        ) if len(keys) > 1 else (value if value != '""' else '')}}
```

I tested the same code with this updated `_dig` on 3.6 and that works. If you're using even older versions of Python, I strongly suggest updating (or being very clear in your questions that you're using a very outdated version of Python).

Comment: Note that the `typing` stuff is just there to give a bit more of a sense of what's expected and happening - of course the code works just fine if you remove type hints and the import.

Comment: Sorry, but I am getting TypeError when I tried your code. Is it because of the different python version? I am using Python 3.6.5

Comment: This is the error I am getting: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'dict' and 'dict'`

Comment: In that case, you are probably not using the latest version of Python (worth mentioning in your question), since that feature was added recently. I'll update my answer to old school syntax momentarily.

Comment: Well, I tried it on 3.8 as well. But same error. Must be added in 3.9.x version, then.

Comment: Correct 3.9.0 - see above for a fix